# HorizontalScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have one `HorizontalScrollView` and one `GridLayout` inside with 3 images. It never scrolls as I thought it should, no matter what I do - with gestures, touch - nothing would make the horizontal scroll.

My XML:

```
<com.app4u.borala.atividades.layout.GridEventoPesqGeo
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/azulActionBarTransparente"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridEventos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rowCount="1" >

        <com.app4u.borala.atividades.layout.ImageViewEventoPesqGeo
            android:id="@+id/imageEvento1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/background_evento_temp" />

        <com.app4u.borala.atividades.layout.ImageViewEventoPesqGeo
            android:id="@+id/imageEvento2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/background_evento_temp" />

        <com.app4u.borala.atividades.layout.ImageViewEventoPesqGeo
            android:id="@+id/imageEvento3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/background_evento_temp" />
    </GridLayout>
</com.app4u.borala.atividades.layout.GridEventoPesqGeo>
```

My class GridEventoPesqGeo:

```
public class GridEventoPesqGeo extends HorizontalScrollView {

public GridEventoPesqGeo(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public GridEventoPesqGeo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public GridEventoPesqGeo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, (int) (parentHeight * 0.225));
}
}
```

My class ImageViewEventoPesqGeo:

```
public class ImageViewEventoPesqGeo extends ImageView{

public ImageViewEventoPesqGeo(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ImageViewEventoPesqGeo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ImageViewEventoPesqGeo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    //int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    MarginLayoutParams lpimgFooter = (MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
    lpimgFooter.bottomMargin = (int) (parentWidth * 0.015);
    lpimgFooter.leftMargin = (int) (parentWidth * 0.015);
    lpimgFooter.rightMargin = (int) (parentWidth * 0.015);
    lpimgFooter.topMargin = (int) (parentWidth * 0.015);
    setLayoutParams(lpimgFooter);

    this.setMeasuredDimension((int) (parentWidth * 0.33), (int) (parentWidth * 0.33));
}
}
```

My Java classes just make the `width` and `height` proportional depending on the phone's screen size..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source of `HorizontalScrollView` `onMeasure()`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if (!mFillViewport) {
        return;
    }

    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
        return;
    }

    if (getChildCount() > 0) {
        final View child = getChildAt(0);
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        if (child.getMeasuredWidth() < width) {
            final FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int childHeightMeasureSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec, mPaddingTop
                    + mPaddingBottom, lp.height);
            width -= mPaddingLeft;
            width -= mPaddingRight;
            int childWidthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that if mFillViewPort is true, it'll return without ever reaching your code. Since you set it to true in xml, no wonder your code is not executed.

Comment: if my viewport is false, don't appear nothing, but if is true, show me the images (my xml is true)... but nothing of this things make the scroll work..

Comment: Instead of overriding `onMeasure`, why not use LayoutParams to manage the size and margins? You need to implement `onMeasure` correctly, or else it won't scroll.

Comment: because the size is proportional depending on the phone's screen.. so I need the parentWidth and parentHeight. I cut the method onMeasure of my class to use original method, and the problem persists.. if I delete my class and use the native HorizontalScrollView the problem persists too.. i don't know what I do now =(

Comment: if I change HorizontalScrollView to ScrollView works as well, but top to bottom and I wanna left to right..